# Are there any examples of code with node.js/socket.io/p5.js & es6 classes?

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, socket.io, p5.js

I know this question is a little too broad and probably this is not the place to ask it, but I really tried my best to look for examples that combine all 4 of these but I didn't seem to find any.

Comment: node, socket.io & es6 are frequently found together.

Comment: Yeah but without p5

Answer (score 0):

You can search on the github by clicking the following url and filter es6 projects by looking into source codes.
https://github.com/search?q=nodejs+socket.io+p5.js